# Building with c2hs and cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal, c2hs

I have a problem where cabal will not do dependency resolution on `.chs` files,
that is, if `A.chs` depends on `B.chs` (or really `B.chi`) then cabal will not
figure it out and call c2hs on the files in the correct order. I know that gtk2hs
uses a custom buildscript, however it is rather complicated and specialized for
gtk2hs. Is there an easier way of manually/automatically doing `.chs` dependency
resolution (by, for instance, listing out the files in the correct order)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, cabal will process `exposed-modules` by
the order they are listed, I guess only if there are
no dependencies to consider or maybe this behavior is
specific to `.chs` files. In order to manually resolve dependencies
one can simply order the modules correctly in the cabal file.